# RSpec tests failing with undefined method `validate_uniqueness_of'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

With Rails 5 and RSpec 3.5, I'm getting the following error.

```
  1) User
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:auth_token)}

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `validate_uniqueness_of' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User:0x007fab919f8cf
8>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've googled around for the right syntax but couldn't find the solution. Does anyone have an idea of what to use here? Thanks

Comment: I bet you don't have https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers gem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add the gem to the Gemfile:

**Gemfile**

```
group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end
```

And include it:

**spec/rails_helper.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include(Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel, type: :model)
  config.include(Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveRecord, type: :model)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I made it work by adding this:

**Gemfile**

```
group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end
```

**rails_helper.rb**

```
require 'shoulda/matchers'

Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

**.rspec**

```
--color
--require spec_helper
--require rails_helper
```

Answer (score 0):

add the below line to spec_helper.rb. it will fix the above error.
config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!